# Why increment on data pointed by Pointer crashing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ Char Pointer Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226829/c-c-char-pointer-crash)

```
char *p = "atl";
char c;
c = ++*p; //crashing here
```

Why it is crashing?

I know the memory is not created for pointer increment should have be done on data.

Comment: This question has been asked many, many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226829/c-c-char-pointer-crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437318/why-does-this-code-crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972915/string-constants-vs-char-arrays-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142988/c-pointer-arithmetic-on-characters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090610/c-char-pointer-problem just to name a few

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`p` points to `const` data which is the string literal `"atl"`; that means, `*p` cannot be changed. But you're trying to change it by writing `++*p`. That is why its crashing at runtime.

In fact, most compilers would give warning when you write `char *p ="atl"`. You should write:

```
const char *p ="atl";
```

If you write so, then the compiler would give error when you write `++*p` at compilation time itself. Detection of error at compile time is better than detection of error at runtime.  See the *compilation* error here now:

- http://www.ideone.com/fvBpx

The compilation error is:

> prog.cpp:7: error: increment of read-only location ‘* p’

---

However, if you write

```
 char p[] = "atl";
 char c = ++*p;  //ok
```

then its correct now. Because now `p` is an array which is created out of the string literal `"atl"`. It doesn't point to the string literal *itself* anymore. So you can change the content of the array.

Comment: char str1[] = {'s', 'o','m','e'};
char str2[] = {'s','o','m','e','\0'};
char *p = str1;
char c = ++*p; is above program different ?(it is not crashing)

Comment: thanks i understood the point